# Express.js won't let me use Handlebars?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm trying to install an Express.js application with Handlebars. I install it with this command:

```
express beatwire --hbs
```

However, whenever I do type that it comes up with this:

```
   create : beatwire
   create : beatwire/package.json
   create : beatwire/app.js
   create : beatwire/public
   create : beatwire/public/javascripts
   create : beatwire/public/images
   create : beatwire/public/stylesheets
   create : beatwire/public/stylesheets/style.css
   create : beatwire/routes
   create : beatwire/routes/index.js
   create : beatwire/routes/users.js
   create : beatwire/views
   create : beatwire/views/index.jade
   create : beatwire/views/layout.jade
   create : beatwire/views/error.jade
   create : beatwire/bin
   create : beatwire/bin/www
```

In other words, it's only letting me use Jade and won't let me use Handlebars. I've installed Handlebars like 5 times and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. What's going on?

Comment: You need to add `--view=hbs` as another argument.

Comment: @GovindRai so type it like: express beatwire --view=hbs or do i type it type express beatwire --hbs--view=hbs

Comment: Owen, did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Scaffold your app with express-generator like so:

```
express beatwire --view=hbs
```

You should get the following output:

```
 ~/Documents  => express beatwire --view=hbs

   create : beatwire
   create : beatwire/package.json
   create : beatwire/app.js
   create : beatwire/public
   create : beatwire/routes
   create : beatwire/routes/index.js
   create : beatwire/routes/users.js
   create : beatwire/public/javascripts
   create : beatwire/public/images
   create : beatwire/views
   create : beatwire/views/index.hbs
   create : beatwire/views/layout.hbs
   create : beatwire/views/error.hbs
   create : beatwire/public/stylesheets
   create : beatwire/public/stylesheets/style.css
   create : beatwire/bin
   create : beatwire/bin/www

   install dependencies:
     $ cd beatwire && npm install

   run the app:
     $ DEBUG=beatwire:* npm start
```

If you try to do both you will get this:

> warning: option `--hbs' has been renamed to`--view=hbs'

Comment: It still tries to make it a jade file.

Comment: Go ahead and remove your app, if you're just starting, `rm -rf beatwire` and try it again? If not, remove and reinstall express-generator. `npm un express-generator && npm i -g express-generator`.

Comment: Tried it, it still won't make it a handlebars file. It still will only do jade D:

Comment: @Owen Can you provide your express version `express --version` and did your uninstall and reinstall?

Comment: 4.0.0 and yes I did reinstall

Comment: @Owen Could you update your Express? My version is 4.1.14. Also, what handlebars package have you installed? Here is the link for the express-handlebars package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars. Also, find out about your outdated packages: `npm outdated`. Then update the package or packages that you want manually as: `npm update --save package_name`.

Comment: Updated, same problem. I did install that package.

Comment: Ah man. I dunno then :/ I pushed a handlebars express scaffolding to my github. Go ahead and download it for now if you need it urgently: https://github.com/govindrai/Express-Handlebars-Scaffolding